# How to keep the numerical integration when an event occurs?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I'm numerically integrating the following system,

```
f[r_] = 0.904965 - (1 + 12.7028/r^2) (1 - 2/r)
dϕdλ = 1/r[λ]^2;
eqc = r'[λ] == Sqrt[f[r[λ]]/(dϕdλ^2)];
```

with the numerical routine,

```
sc = NDSolve[{eqc, r[0] == 4.85744 + .003},r, {λ, 0., 40*Pi}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 20, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}]
```

However, I need to keep the integration when the solution reaches the radius `r = 4.85744` or `r = 11.3301`, which are the values where the derivative changes the signal.

Technically, what I need is: When `r[λ] = 4.85744` or `r[λ] = 11.3301` keep the integration with `r'[λ]==-Sqrt[f[r[λ]]/(dϕdλ^2)]`.

In my code, the integration just stops at this point. I would like to keep integrating with opposite velocity when the solution reaches these two radii, is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There was a little mistake but I've fixed and edited the post, I hope I made it clear @ChrisK.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: There is a solution with reflection from point `r=11.3301`, but there is no solution with reflection from point `r=4.85744`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev That’s exactly the solution that I want to integrate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to square the equation `eqc` and differentiate it once by lambda. Then we can use `WhenEvent[r[\[Lambda]] == 4.85744, r'[\[Lambda]] -> -r'[\[Lambda]]]`.

```
F[r_] := 2 (0.904965` - (1 + 12.7028`/r^2) (1 - 2/r)) r + ((
     25.4056` (1 - 2/r))/r^3 - (2 (1 + 12.7028`/r^2))/r^2) r^2
mu[r_] := Sqrt[0.904965 - (1 + 12.7028/r^2) (1 - 2/r)]*r;
eqc = 2*r''[\[Lambda]] == F[r[\[Lambda]]]; r0 = 4.86;
sc = NDSolve[{eqc, r[0] == r0, r'[0] == mu[r0], 
   WhenEvent[r[\[Lambda]] == 4.85744, 
    r'[\[Lambda]] -> -r'[\[Lambda]]]}, r, {\[Lambda], 0., 80*Pi}, 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}]

Plot[Evaluate[r[\[Lambda]] /. sc], {\[Lambda], 0., 80*Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 12}, AxesLabel -> {"\[Lambda]", "r"}]
```

[image: fig1]